# Difference between \n and CR

Tags: c, newline, carriage-return

According to the ASCII table, value of the new line character(\n) is 13 whereas value of Carriage Return (CR) is 13 . When trying to write a program that detects if enter key is pressed. ıs it safe to use the either value  ?

```
 if( ( kr=getchar() ) == 13 )

     puts("Enter Key Pressed ") ;
```

or

```
 if( ( kr=getchar() ) == '\n' )

     puts("Enter Key Pressed ") ;
```

Comment: C is not guaranteed to use ASCII.

Comment: Short answer is: Use `\n`

Comment: The value of the line feed character is 10, rather. So your question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: you should always use `'\n'`.

Longer answer: Yes, Carriage Return is ASCII 13 is `'\r'` in C.
Newline is ASCII 10 (not 13) and is `'\n'` in C.

But the key you press is *not* necessarily the same as the character you'll receive in a C program, for two reasons:

1. The operating system may map things.  For example, under Unix and Linux, in the normal ("cooked") mode of the terminal driver, the Return key maps to (sends) a Linefeed.
2. In C, the preferred character for "the new line" is always `'\n'`.  Even if the underlying operating system has different conventions, under normal circumstances your program is supposed to receive a `'\n'` for a new line.  (Similarly, when you print a `'\n'`, it gets translated to carriage return, linefeed, or a carriage return / linefeed pair, depending on your OS's conventions.)

Finally, whatever you do, even if you do need to handle Carriage Returns explicitly, please use `'\r'` and `'\n'` in C programs.  Don't make your readers know what the magic numbers 10 and 13 (or 0x0a and 0x0d) are.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either one, but you definitely should use `\n` because people can read it without an external reference.

Comment: by external reference , do you mean the ascii table ?

Answer (score 0):

I think both values are the same, but for making a more readable code you should use "\n", or use comments in the other case to explain what are you expecting by keyboard.